# textarea shrinks in size if nothing inside it

Tags: css

I have a just a simple textarea with id #studentselect

```
#studentselect{
    max-width:350px;    
    min-width:350px;    
}
```

Now the issue I am having is that if there is nothing in the textarea when testing this in IE9 in compatability view, then the textarea's width is shrunk to like 20px. My question is that how can I get the default textarea width to be 350px if there is nothing in textarea?

Comment: Have you tried `width:350px`?

Comment: @Asad My apologies, realised I uploaded wrong style sheet when I tried thisp previously, your correct.

Comment: You probably also want to add resize:none;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#studentselect{
  width:350px;    
}
```

I've uploaded [this simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8REzj/).